# CRM 2011 Ribbon CheckBox Checked by Default

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

How can a checkbox on the ribbon be checked by default?
There does not appear to be an attribute mentioned on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327840.aspx).
Can it be done with JavaScript?

I have a checkbox on the queue view, which while checked should keep the queue auto refreshing:

```xml
<CustomAction Id="Mscrm.HomepageGrid.queueitem.MainTab.Workflow.Controls.CustomAction" Location="Mscrm.HomepageGrid.queueitem.MainTab.Management.Controls._children" Sequence="60">
  <CommandUIDefinition>
    <CheckBox  Id="Mscrm.HomepageGrid.queueitem.MainTab.Workflow.Controls.CheckBox" LabelText="Auto Refresh" TemplateAlias="o3" ToolTipTitle="Queue Auto Refresh" ToolTipDescription="Periodically auto refresh this queue" Command="Mscrm.HomepageGrid.queueitem.MainTab.Workflow.Controls.Command" Sequence="60" />
  </CommandUIDefinition>
</CustomAction>
```

The auto-refresh is working fine and is on by default.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain but I believe the Microsoft Ribbon between application is fairly similar.

So you could try; [CheckBox element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd371607%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): `ApplicationDefaults.IsChecked`

*This is total guess in all honesty*

Comment: It will not go into CRM with that attribute, thanks for the answer anyway.